# IMAGE TOUCH EVENT IN ANDROID CAMERA VIEW

Tags: android, android-intent

I am showing one png image in camera view and i want to generate a touch/click event when i touch/click the image and open a browser with some url in event handler my code is

```
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override

      ImageView  iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
      iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.cdacb.in"));
            startActivityForResult(browserIntent,0);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

this intent might be helpful to you:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
   intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.cdacb.in"));
   startActivity(intent);
```